# Conditionally remove lines with less than 4 characters

Tags: bash, text-processing, awk, sed

I want to trim lines less than 4 characters, except if the line begins with `#` or `!`.

Sample input:

```
aa
bbb
 
   
dasasdsad
! f
#
!
# s
a
&B@*!
```

Output:

```
dasasdsad
! f
#
!
# s
&B@*!
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With `grep`:

```
< file.in grep -E '^[#!]|.{4}' > file.out
```

That is, select lines that either start with `#` or `!` or contain a sequence of 4 characters.

Or with `awk`:

```
< file.in awk '/^[#!]/ || length >= 4' > file.out
```

Or with `sed`:

```
< file.in sed -e '/^[#!]/b' -e '/.\{4\}/!d' > file.out
```

Answer (score -6):

You can try something like this, code not tested:

```
while read line;
do
var=$(echo $line | awk '{ print length }')
if [ $var -le 4 ]; then
echo $line >> tmp.file
fi
done < your.file
```

This are 2 steps, while read, it writes the lines of less than 4 characters to tmp.file.
With `comm -23 your.file tmp.file` you compare both files, suppress common lines and `> you.new.file` is the final saved version

Comment: You may want to read [Why is using a shell loop to process text considered bad practice?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/169716). You could also run your script by shellcheck.

Comment: You seem to have syntax errors in your script, you also call `awk` once for each line in the file, which will be slow.

Comment: Whilst you both might be right, I wrote  "You can try something like this, code not tested: "

Comment: Whilst you both may be right, it's not my intention, to write the script for the OP, but just to provide one option/direction, how it can be archived. I personally use and prefer loops, as they allow me a better reuse of existing codes and in case needed, store results as variables and obviously, I am not the only one.

Comment: I was brought here by some "low quality" flags and would recommend that you do your best to test future Answers before posting them. Stack Exchange aims to be a high-quality repository of Questions and Answers.